# SQL - syntax error when USER input single quote in Textbox

Tags: c#, sql

In C#, WPF, When user enter Single Quote (') 
while saving that data in sqlite, it gives me an error : SQL logic error or missing database in 'S: syntax error. 
P.S. ONLY WHEN USER ENTER AN Single Quote (') into the Textbox field.
Not with backslash () nor with (")or (`).Those works fine.

Any Suggestion...

Comment: Seems like you need to escape the `'` (single quote). It would be better for you to provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can see what's wrong.

Comment: Seems like your question is not really related to wpf or any user input. It's about sql.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are using string concatenation to produce SQL. This is a very bad idea! Read up on *SQL Injection Attacks*.

Instead you should be using prepared statements.

Comment: my Query is Query = "insert into Product (P_SrNo,P_Name) values ('" + this.TB_srno.Text + "','" + this.TB_Name.Text + "' )  ";

Comment: Yep. That's string concatenation and it's a bad idea. Use the technique described [in this article](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter).

Comment: If you don't protect yourself from SQL injection attacks, someone can easily delete your entire database.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You can tell i am newbie. I will correct it.

Comment: You're welcome. Everyone's a newbie at some point! Usually it doesn't matter, but in this case it's important to get it right.